# Performance of Pypy's islower(), isupper()

Tags: python, string, performance, pypy

I have a program in which `str.isupper()` is called in a very tight loop, and takes around 25% of my running time.

It strikes me that `isupper` and `islower` are much slower than other `isX` methods, such as `isalnum`, `isalpha`, `isdigit` and so on. (Note: in cpython all the methods are equally slow.)

```
$ pypy -mtimeit "'a'.islower()"       - 0.0158  usec per loop
$ pypy -mtimeit "'a'.isalpha()"       - 0.00251 usec per loop
$ pypy -mtimeit "'a'.isupper()"       - 0.0164  usec per loop
$ pypy -mtimeit "'a'.isdigit()"       - 0.00236 usec per loop
```

I can make a much faster `isupper` method myself by

```
isupper = lambda c: 'A' <= c <= 'Z'
```

Which runs in reasonable `0.00393 usec per loop`. Of course this version doesn't do 'work' for unicode strings, but my strings are certainly all 8bit ascii.

---

My question is if there is a way to 'tell' Python to skip the fancy unicode tests when just working with simple 'a-z'?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Note that your lambda only works for single-character strings. The `isX` methods handle multi-character strings; `isupper` and `islower` return true if all cased characters in the string are upper/lowercase and there is at least one cased character, while `isalpha` and `isdigit` return true if all characters in the string are alphabetic/digits and there is at least one character.

Comment: Python3 already skips the "fancy unicode tests" when it knows the strings are ASCII. People have thought about this before you.

Comment: @user2357112: I get the same results for python2 and python3. Also for pypy2 and pypy3. And yes, I only need single characters.

Comment: @doukremt: Thank you, but then how do you describe the benchmarks?

Comment: Note that your "much faster" implementation *utterly* fails with unicode input. Since `isX` assume to have to deal with unicode it wouldn't be so strange that a naive implementation, that does much less checks, would be faster.

Comment: Python 2: The methods on the `str` type are about byte strings.  They don't know anything about unicodes.  There are no unicodes involves here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason for the difference, but I do know that the benchmarks are flawed.  An expression like `"a".islower()` in a loop is constant-folded away.  It completely disappears... you might as well time `pass`.

We can check that `"a".isalpha()` and `pass` execute at exactly the same speed: it's the speed of an empty loop.  As for `"a".islower()`, I'm not sure to understand, but it's sometimes slower for me too, and sometimes not --- even though it's always measuring the speed of an empty loop, as we can check (see "jitviewer" if you're interested).  Mysteries of CPUs?

(Note that this has been measured on a very recent pypy; some time ago islower() and isupper() suffered a missing optimization, and were not constant-folded.)

Comment: How would you fix the benchmarks to avoid getting folded away?

Comment: @ThomasAhle Make them operate over something that isn't a constant every iteration of the loop, it may be difficult to express with timeit.